# Error heredoc PHP: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file"

Tags: php

Revisando un código, encontré algo en notación Heredoc:

```
<?php

$html = <<<XXX
            <script type="text/javascript">
            ...
            </script>
XXX; //must be begin in column 0 or ERR

echo $html;
```

Este código, al ejecutarse, produce un error y no sé por qué:

> ```
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in D:\PHP\heredoc.php on line 10
> ```

- *La línea 10 es la última del script*.

Comment: cual es la linea 10 que menciona el error?

Comment: El error se genera en la última línea del script, porque nunca se cerró el HEREDOC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La sintaxis [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) establece para la etiqueta de cierre que:

- Tiene que estar al principio de la línea.
- No se permite nada más que el tag de cierre en esa línea.

---

Es decir, **no puede estar ese comentario en la misma línea** que el cierre:

```
$heredoc = <<<XXX
    ...
XXX; // Este comentario genera que no se cierre (ERROR) <----
```

Corregido:

```
<?php

$html = <<<XXX
            <script type="text/javascript">
            ...
            </script>
XXX;
//must begin in column 0 or ERR

echo $html;
```

Comment: Bien visto lo del comentario